# Video autoplay not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube

I have written below code to autoplay youtube video in my page.
But it's not working.
I have also set autoplay to true , but still does not work.

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='230' height='200'
                                            id='single1' name='single1'>
   <param name='movie' value='/Scripts/player.swf' />
   <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true' />
   <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always' />
   <param name='wmode' value='transparent' />
   <param name='autoplay' value='true' />
   <param name='flashvars' value='file=http://youtu.be/DGcWqEu8pY&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=FF6666&lightcolor=6666FF&screencolor=000000' />

    <embed type='application/x-shockwave-flash' id='single2' name='single2' src='/Scripts/player.swf' width='320' height='200' bgcolor='undefined' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'                                                     autoplay='true' wmode='transparent' flashvars='file=http://youtu.be/DGcWq-Eu8pY&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=FF6666&lightcolor=6666FF&screencolor=000000'>
                                                </embed>
</object>
```

Can anyone please help me to autoplay video on page load..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution.
I used below code and it worked like a charm.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 320px; height: 200px;"
                                            data="https://www.youtube.com/v/DGcWq-Eu8pY?color2=FBE9EC&amp;autoplay=1&amp;version=3">
                                            <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/DGcWq-Eu8pY?color2=FBE9EC&amp;autoplay=1&amp;version=3" />
                                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                                            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                                        </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use jplayer2: http://jplayer.org/
It's easy to put a js code on head to autoplay a video.
something like:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4v: "http://www.mysite.com/img/video/video.mp4",
                    ogv: "hthttp://www.mysite.com/img/video/video.ogv"
                }).jPlayer("play");
            });
```

and in your html code just

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```